# iPhone makes calls on its own

Tags: iphone, ios, call

My wife's iPhone went crazy over the past week.

There is a large number of calls to and from Romania in it's call log (5-10 a day). These include outgoing, incoming and missed calls (all of which she never initiated or received).

Most calls are under a minute but some are as long as 29 minutes. The phone never rings or vibrates. Also, it seems the conversations only appear in the call log on the phone as they are not visible on our account with the phone carrier.

Both EE and Apple are clueless as to what's going on.It looks like we are actually seeing somebody else's call log.

Has anyone encountered such a problem? Any suggestion on what we could try to stop this?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question.

Comment: I wonder if you are a victim of SIM card hijacking? You may want to call your carrier's customer service and mention that as a possibility.

Comment: I had called the phone carrier. Nothing shown on our account.

Comment: Could you check any unknown app doing so, in storage preferably? Also calling will require microphone too at some point of time so check the Mic permissions in Settings → Privacy. (Notify me by @ankii)

Comment: Tried them both, nothing suspicious. Neither unknown app nor microphone access.
But as I said the calls don't actually happen, they are in the list only. It is like seeing somebody else's call list on my phone, along with my own.

Comment: So after an hour on the phone with specialist from Apple we seem to have managed to sort it out. Factory reset and restoring the phone from an earlier backup got rid of the bug for now.